# How to refer to Google translate result box in VBA

Tags: vba

I'd like to refer to Google translate result box in VBA. Here's my piece of code: Kom.Offset(0, 1).Value = .getElementByID("result_box").Value but I receive an error that "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: Use the API instead? https://cloud.google.com/translate/

Comment: I've got to do it not using API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-input elements don't have a `Value` property.  Try:

```
.getElementByID("result_box").innerText
```

Comment: The `result_box` is no longer included in Google translate results (~summer 2019) but this http request method does.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47249553/1898524