# Google translate not translating in IE when website opened from vba

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, google-translate

Google translate is not translating text (Japanese to English). The function always returns "" when the website is opened and the text is input using the following code:

```
Function OutlookGetTransItem(IE As Object, URL As String, trans_text As String) As String
Dim t As Date

If trans_text = "" Then OutlookGetTransItem = trans_text: Exit Function

Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate URL

    While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    .Document.querySelector("#source").Value = trans_text

    Dim translation As Object, translationText As String
    t = Timer
    Do
        On Error Resume Next
        Set translation = .Document.querySelector(".tlid-translation.translation")
        translationText = translation.innerText
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    Loop While translationText = vbNullString
    OutlookGetTransItem = translationText
End With
End Function
```

IE gives this error when i try to manually click the translate arrow/button on the website:
SCRIPT5025: The URI to be decoded is not a valid encoding
translate_m.js (207,484)

This is the URL i am navigating to:

https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=ja&tl=en

Here is the text i am setting as `trans_text` this text is taken from an outlook email using its `.body` property:

関係各位

いつもお世話になっております。
    「111117_NAM_L42L_TR2k2_3悪_第1部第2部.pdf（議事板書)」を送付いたします。よろしくお願い致します。

結論：途中
　　下記13件の課題がありﾌｫﾛｰを実施する

ｴﾝ担,ﾌﾟﾛｾﾝ
　　　　　       ・残課題対応を実施する事（Dﾚﾝｼﾞｱｲﾄﾞﾙ回転検討,ｱｲﾄﾞﾙ振動ﾃﾞｰﾀ入手,制御不具合対応,全ROM定数ﾁｪｯｸ,燃料PUMP不具合調査,冷房性能未達対応）
　　　　　　     ・T/M IPのFKとFKk2との比較を提示する事
　　　　　　     ・ ｻｰﾓｽﾀｯﾄのﾒｰｶｰを再確認すること
　　　　　        ・始動ｴﾝｽﾄﾁｪｯｸﾘｽﾄの再ﾁｪｯｸを実施する事（ｴﾝｽﾄ余裕率,ﾊﾟｰｼﾞの判断,AF/M電源投入特性）
　　　　始動ISC　　
　　　　　　　  ・不懸残項目の対応を実施する事（車両振動,始動即Rｾﾚｸﾄｴﾝｽﾄ,A/F回転総ﾁｪｯｸ,常温始動軽質確認,かぶり,ｾﾚｸﾄｱｲﾌﾗ,PCVﾊﾝﾁﾝｸﾞ確認,即始動確認,押し出され確認） 
　　　　　　　  ・H1を最終仕様でまとめる事　　　　
　　　　　　　  ・各相場ﾁｪｯｸﾃﾞｰﾀの古いL42Lのﾗｲﾝを削除する事
　　　　　　　  ・ﾌﾞﾚｰｷｴﾝｽﾄ回転低下時の車両振動への影響を確認する事
　　　　　　　  ・低温始動時のTpを確認する事
　　　　　　　　・ｸﾗﾝｷﾝｸﾞ回転数の0℃の目標値の出所を確認する事
　　　　台上適合
　　　　　　　　・H2全ROM定数ﾁｪｯｸを実施する事
　　　　　　　　・不懸残項目の対応を実施する事（R/Lｻｰｼﾞ,暖機中ﾗﾌｱｲﾄﾞﾙ,ﾛｼﾞｯｸﾊﾞｸﾞ修正後の確認,ﾌﾞﾛｯｸ_ﾍｯﾄ変更後のﾉｯｸ確認）
                    ・BCV確認のTH/Cつまりﾃﾞｰﾀの再確認を実施する事（ｱﾙﾐﾎﾞｱ化）

<\Jp-nml-fs-a01\U00\PT共通（インフラ）\A01_集約(フリー)\3悪格納ﾌｫﾙﾀﾞ2\111117_NAM_L42L_TR2k2_3悪>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter your URL slightly and let the browser handle the encoding of the URL. Here I am reading your text from a cell. When the site does a translation it generates a new URL which has a query string parameter of `text=<your string to translate>`; so add the `text=` onto your start URL and concatenate in your phrase for translation.

Remember you need to close your IE instance at some point. I am not a fan of passing IE as an object in this manner and would probably look to having it held in a class which generates the IE object in class `Class_Initialize()`. You then instantiate that class with a variable in the sub.

I frequently forget that the appropriate navigate method I believe is now `.navigate2`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, trans_text As String
    Const URL As String = "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=ja&tl=en&text="
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    trans_text = [A1].Value
    Debug.Print OutlookGetTransItem(ie, URL, trans_text)
    ie.Quit
End Sub

Public Function OutlookGetTransItem(ByVal ie As Object, ByVal URL As String, ByVal trans_text As String) As String
    Dim t As Date

    If trans_text = vbNullString Then OutlookGetTransItem = trans_text: Exit Function

    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate2 URL & trans_text

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim translation As Object, translationText As String
        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set translation = .document.querySelector(".tlid-translation.translation")
            translationText = translation.innerText
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While translationText = vbNullString
        OutlookGetTransItem = translationText
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I will try this but in the past i needed to do my own encoding before sending the url to IE, i still have many subs and functions that can do this. The issue with this is that IE has a 2000 character limit on URLs and Japanese text becomes extremely long when encoded. I thought that using this code: `.Document.querySelector("#source").Value = trans_text` would be a way to bypass that, since google translate website has limit of 5000 (not encoded) characters. If i have a wait command after putting the text into that element will the website make that url instead of my encoding subs?

Comment: Now that I think about it I am positive that when encoded this text block will be over 2000 characters. I'm guessing the error is caused by the website trying to encode the text and it being too long for IE and stopping the website from refreshing/translating the text. What do you think?

Comment: This particular phrase worked for me with IE (I think). Is selenium basic an option?

Comment: Sadly i can only use IE, Edge or Chrome. I only know how to use IE currently.

Comment: That did actually work on IE, although it loses all formatting.

Comment: Last time I used clipboard which copied formatting across as well.

Comment: clipboard to put text into the url or into the input box?

Comment: To retrieve the translation and paste to Excel. For the current version if using your method I think there is an event that needs to be triggered for the translation to happen properly.

Comment: I did some testing and it seems that google translate doesnt format the text back if its over roughly 500 characters. Any reason why that is? or how i can fix it? Regardless i can just give google translate 500 char chunks and it will work just fine.

Comment: I am not aware of that limitation though sounds possible. No idea why. Is the limit exact or approximate?

Comment: Seems like a hard limit, 499 worked, 501 didnt. Maybe the website thinks it will take too long? Not sure Thanks for the help working with the HTML though, really appreciate it.